# code to download a file using python given url,proxy& user credentials

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried the following code. can anyone suggest me another way of doing it since I am getting a connectivity error?

```
import requests
http_proxy  = "https://10.166.252.101:8080"
proxyDict = { "https"  : http_proxy }
url = 'https://reports.virtuefusion.com/gvc/data_extracts/gvc_dbex_user_totals_20190918.csv'
username = 'gvc_bi'
password = 'iExPX50r1aXhBJUvOEfy'
print(requests.get(url, auth=(username, password)).content,proxies=proxyDict)
```

Comment: What is the error my friend?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment as I have less reputation hope this Code works:

```
import requests

proxies = {"http":"http://username:password@proxy_ip:proxy_port"}

r = requests.get("http://www.example.com/", proxies=proxies)

print(r.content)
```

or just an option:

```
import urllib2

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://
username:password@proxyurl:proxyport'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

conn = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org')
return_str = conn.read()
```